# How to download attachment from email using Robotframework

Tags: download, pycharm, robotframework, attachment, email-attachments

I want to download attachment from email in robotframework.But in imapLibrary there is not keyword defined for download attachment.

I can read email body but didn't  fine any solution to download attachment

```
enter code here

open mailbox  host=imap.gmail.com 
user=abc@gmail.com
password = secret
${LATEST}=wait for email  
sender=xyz@gmail.com  timeout=10
${body} =  get email body  ${LATEST}
# log to console  ${body}
# Remove String Using Regexp  ${LATEST}  [^WA ID]
convert to string   ${body}
log to console  ${body}
close mailbox
```

I want to download attachment from email in robotframework.But in imapLibrary there is not keyword defined for download attachment.